# How do I compare two zero-terminated but different length strings in Zig?

Tags: zig

For example where an external C library is returning a fixed-size buffer containing a null-terminated string.

What would be the the equivalent of strcmp() to compare these two buffers? `std.mem.eql` fails because they are different sizes.

```
var string1: [1024]u8 = undefined;
@memset(&string1, 0);
@memcpy(string1[0..3], "foo");

var string2 = "foo";

var result = std.mem.eql(u8, &string1, string2);
try std.testing.expect(result);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest turning your string into a proper slice. For example, using [`std.mem.len`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:mem.len):

```
var buffer: [1024]u8 = undefined;
@memset(&buffer, 0);
@memcpy(buffer[0..3], "foo");

const length = std.mem.len(@as([*:0]u8, @ptrCast(&buffer)));
var string1 = buffer[0..length];
var string2 = "foo";

const result = std.mem.eql(u8, string1, string2);
try std.testing.expect(result);
```

Or better, [`std.mem.span`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:mem.span):

```
var string1 = std.mem.span(@as([*:0]u8, @ptrCast(&buffer)));
```

Or [`std.mem.sliceTo`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:mem.sliceTo):

```
var string1 = std.mem.sliceTo(@as([*:0]u8, @ptrCast(&buffer)), 0);
```

Or, if you know you won't need to use that string more than once and want to "optimize", then you can use [`std.mem.orderZ`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:mem.orderZ):

```
var buffer: [1024]u8 = undefined;
@memset(&buffer, 0);
@memcpy(buffer[0..3], "foo");

var string1 = @as([*:0]u8, @ptrCast(&buffer));
var string2 = "foo";

const result = std.mem.orderZ(u8, string1, string2);
try std.testing.expect(result == .eq);
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot, there is such a function: `std.mem.span`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: `std.mem.orderZ` looks like the closest equivalent to strcmp. It is difficult to find these things in the docs, thank you.